# .NET 7 JsonModelBinder not working with big size POST in IIS

Tags: .net

we implemented a new function for mass messaging and on our local dev machines everything is working. We have a Route in our Controller accepting accepting following parameter

`[FromBody][ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(JsonModelBinder))] List<NewMailDTO> newMessages`

The Data is coming from a form multipart/form-data

I have set up the RequestSizeLimit for the application, the FormOptions as following

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
            {
                x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });
```

and my WebConfig also has

`<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />`

When using my backend local with IIS Express everything works as intended. When deploying it and trying it in production, the "newMessages" List is just empty and I receive an Error because it is null.

Is there anything I am missing, is there anything I need to change in IIS so it is working like it does with my IIS Express / localhost backend?

Thank you

I tried setting up the maxContentLength / RequestSize etc. but nothing worked, it only worked for my localhost

Edit:

This is the ModelBinder I am using where I assume a problem with maybe deserializing the Object? Thats all I can assume

```
public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }


        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(valueAsString, bindingContext.ModelType);
            if (result != null)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum request length exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Comment: IIS has its own limits to be configured check the above answer to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I am not getting the above error (anymore). I had it before and added the above, but for some reason the only error I get is a 500 because the Model is null. On my localhost it is not null. I can only imagine that my ModelBinder is not working correctly but I dont know why

Comment: Then you need to find what causes the 500 response, You may start by checking the Windows Event Log for the errors.

Comment: Sorry but you guys are not reading at all. I said the 500 Error is because there is a NullReferenceException because the "newMessages" is not getting bound to the data I post

either you read and try to give a proper answer or you dont. I got it working now by changing the DTO